# java.lang.NullPointerException: null on AutoWiring a bean in StandAlone App

Tags: javabeans, autowired

When trying to use @AutoWire feature with one of StandAlone Application unable to do so instead getting Null Pointer Exception. Please highlight my mistakes if any. Your help is appreciated.

Spring Ver 5.1.5.RELEASE and we're not using any xml config file to tell spring there are annotated classes to look into instead using @ComponentScan or @EnableAutoConfiguration at the top of AppConfig and boost strap the Context from main() class as a first line. But Autowiring works perfectly with internal bean/java classes of jdk(Environment) but not with custom POJO classes. If we're trying to get through getBean method then it works. But I'm trying to avoid creating context everywhere and using getBean() Please Refer below and help me only with your valuable guidelines.

```
public class ContextMaster {
private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext;
public static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
if (appContext == null) {
appContext =  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ContextConfig.class);
//appContext =  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.xx.xx.xxx","xx.xxx.xxxx.xxx.datamanager");          
logger.debug("Context Invoked !!");
}
return appContext;
}
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = {
        @ComponentScan(basePackages = "xxxxx.datamanager"),
        @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xx.xx.xxx"),
        @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xx.xx.xxx.utils")})

public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        //LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());

        Properties props=new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        props.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"));


    factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
    factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(xx.class, xxxx.class, xxxx.class, xxx.class);
    return factoryBean;


    }

    @Bean


    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
            return transactionManager;


    }  
    }

// Here is NPE thrown when tried with auto-configured bean
    @Component
            public class Good extends Good11 {    
                @Autowired
                private RxxxDyyyyHelper rdh; 
                //RxxxDyyyyHelper rdh = 
    ContextHelper.getApplicationContext().getBean(RxxxDyyyyHelper .class);    
            rdh.setProperty(); // NPE here
            rdh.getProperty(); // NPE 

        }

// Here we're trying to initiate the LosUtils class
public class LosUtils {       
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = `ContextHelper.getApplicationContext();`    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't put the full code here, because your `Good` class won't compile this way..